# Understanding this triple integral by change of variables with constraints $ x+y+z \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

This is an excerpt from my Probability textbook.  The function to be integrated is simply 1 so it's just a simple triple integral.

The way I learned from calculus class to solve such a triple integral by using different limits for $x,y$ & $z$ is like:  $$
\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^{1-x}\int\limits_0^{1-x-y} 1 dz dy dx.$$

It's just this change of variable used here that I can't work out. After changing $x_1, x_2, x_3$ to $s_1, s_2, s_3$, then what? how did they get $1/6$? many thanks

Comment: You don't have a function of $1$, rather you have $f(x,y,z)=zyx$...

Comment: @abiessu: No, the integrand is indeed $1$.

Comment: @joriki: I'm talking about the last statement of the integral at the end...

Comment: Ops my bad. Changing it to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After changing $x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3$   to $s_1 ,s_2 ,s_3$  , then what? how did they get 1/6 ? many thanks

It's an argument from symmetry.

Noting that the probability of an *exact* tie among continuous random variables is infinitesimal, we consider the three of them to be almost surely distinct.   There are $3!$ ways to arrange three distinct real numbers and only one such will be in the required order of magnitudes.   By symmetry, all of these arrangements are equally probable, so, the probability of being so arranged is thus: $$1/6$$

Comment: I get the 1/6 part and why only 1 out of 6 ordering is what we want. But how does a triple integral relate to possible orderings of $s1 \, s2 \, s3$?

Comment: @DanSoren: The triple integral is over the part of the unit cube corresponding to one of the six orderings. The volume of the unit cube is $1$, so by the symmetry argument each such part must have volume $1/6$.